# ¿Cómo saber el día de la semana de una fecha? MySQL

Tags: mysql

alguien que me pueda orientar, es que tengo una tabla donde **day_index** es el día de la semana, son 13 días porque son 2 semanas, mediante una consulta quiero obtener el día

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada número del **day_index** es un día de las 2 semanas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me parece una buena aproximación y menos escalable el hecho de almacenar los días de la forma en que lo propones

Comment: Hola @BetaM sí lo mismo pienso, pero es un sistema de una base de datos de una plataforma ya estructurada y esta así, y me piden sacar esos datos :c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dos opciones sin tabla adicional.

Una basada en https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334077/1423096 que utiliza el idioma del sistema via [`DAYNAME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) y [`ADDDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) trae el nombre del día sumándole N días a una fecha que sabes que es domingo.

La otra basada en https://stackoverflow.com/a/37333909/1423096 que utiliza una lista via [`ELT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) y [`MOD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) trae el nombre de una lista según su índice haciendo `N MOD 7 + 1` el resto de dividir por 7, + 1

```sql
SELECT
  id, DAYNAME(ADDDATE("2016-01-03", T.day_index))
FROM Table1 T;

SELECT
  id, ELT(
    T.day_index MOD 7 + 1, 
    'Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 
    'Jueves', 'Tu cuerpo lo sabe', 'Sábado'
  )
FROM Table1 T;
```

el fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c3a1a/6

Answer (score 4):

Creo que has enfocado mal el problema. principlamente debes tener una relación entre tablas para poder hacer un JOIN  y tener la relación.
Personalmente haría que una columna registrara el DATE y a traves de dos queries podrías obtener los datos:

```
SELECT DAYOFMONTH('1998-02-03');--> con esta query obtienes un 3 (el dia del mes 1-31).
SELECT DAYOFWEEK('1998-02-03'); --> con esta query obtienes el dia de la semana (1=SUNDAY, 2=MONDAY).
```

una vez obtenido esto puedes tratarlo en tu backend, con un map por ejemplo donde lo que trae la segunda query seria la key y el value serian los días de la semana correspondientes.